# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error in windows server 2012 R2

Tags: iis, .net-core, web-config

I'm trying to install a **dotnet core application in IIS** on a machine with **windows server 2012 R2** installed, but I'm getting Error 500.19 with the following characteristics:
[image]

According to my searches, I already tested the following solutions:

- I used a xml validator to validate both webconfig and applicationHost;
- I uninstalled all versions of dotnet core and installed just the 2.1.1 bundle (with hosting and runtime);
- I copied the project to another machine, with windows 10 installed and with dotnet core 2.1.1, and it works, but not in the machine I want;
- I checked all the IIS features following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2);
- I changed ApplicationPool to **No Managed Code**;
- I also noticed that doing **dotnet --version** on command line it was not working, I fixed that (now it's working as supposed, saying that I need SDK to do this operation).

Following is my IIS information:
[image]

And next is my **webconfig**:
[image]

So, any idea why I'm still getting this error.

I appreciate some help =).

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I noticed that removing a line on my web.config I can access some functionalities of IIS without giving me the Error 0x8007000d. This is the line:

> `<aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:10:00" processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Glintt.BedSide.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />`

So the problem is obviously here. Any idea why this line generates this error?

Comment: 0x8007000d means there is something wrong with your web.config file. first of all, you need to ensure the application works just fine in your development environment. I suggest you could also check the event viewer to see the other error message.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The application is working fine on my development environment. Check event viewer is a great idea, but the application does not run so event Viewer doesn't show any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install .NET Core 2.2 Runtime & Hosting Bundle for Windows.
This version for example: [.NET Core 2.2 Runtime & Hosting Bundle for Windows](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.2.6-windows-hosting-bundle-installer)